# How do I configure Oracle DB 11g Enterprise to be able to be accessed from HTTPS PORT?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm trying to create a TSA Listener so I could access my Oracle database from HTTPS Port. I already checked edelivery.oracle.com but I found no Web Tier for Windows. Is there any other way for me to configure my TSA Listener? If it's useful, I already have an Apache in my XAMPP but I already have a database in MySQL RDBMS. If possible, I need to configure them to coexist with each other.

Comment: Are you asking about the Oracle RDBMS (flagship product of Oracle corp) or the MySQL RDBMS (a different product by Oracle corp)??? Two different products; two different set of tags; two different answers. Thabks for clarification.

Comment: @Mucharl Klutz Sorry for being unclear but I'm referring to Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with this HTTPS connection? DML operations? XML? Typically (for most DML-type stuff) you will need an intermediate application server solution like Tomcat, running Oracle REST Data Services or some such to make a JDBC connection back to the database.

Comment: @pmdba It's DML

Comment: Are you trying to create a REST API? HTTPS isn't really designed to handle SQL transactions, and Oracle RDBMS doesn't have a good built in listener for it.

Comment: @pmdba No, I'm just trying to acces and do DML operations on Oracle RDBMS from my browser.

Comment: You can't do that over https. Must use jdbc or native Oracle client, or REST-enable your database with Oracle REST Data Services. https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/faq-rest-data-services.html

Comment: You could also consider APEX: https://apex.oracle.com/en/. It would give you a UI, but would still need ORDS as the network listener.

Comment: @pmdba  I see, thanks for the help. I'd try to configure ORDS as Listener for APEX. I'd probably do something else with the post.

Comment: TCPS is a supported protocol for SQL*Net. You'll still need to use a real Oracle Database client application such as SQL*Plus, not just a web browser. Here's a link potentially describing how to do this, but I haven't spent the time to get it to work. https://rbikblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/21/tcps-listener-configuration-for-oracle-database-12c/